# Using semaphores to allow either a main thread to run or a group of other threads to run

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, semaphore

I have a main thread that creates n new threads to do some subtask, but I only want the main code to execute when the n threads are locked, and when the main thread is sleeping, the n threads run.

```
def main_thread(n):
    sem = threading.Semaphore(n)

    for i in n:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=threading_fun, args=(sem,))
        thread.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(60)

        for i in n:
            sem.acquire()

        # do something
        sem.release(n)


def thread_fun(sem):
    while True:
        sem.acquire()
        # do something
        sem.release()
```

Right now I have something like this in Python using semaphores which achieves the goal, but I am wondering if there is a better way. Mainly, I am curious if there is a way around acquiring the semaphore n times in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

So now that I correctly understand your problem.  Yes, you want to use a condition variable.

With a little bit of cleverness, I could probably simplify this.  But I think this is the clearest implementation.  `counter` is a counter of the number of workers running.  `main_thread_wants_to_run` is the main thread telling the workers to pause.

Feel free to wrap `counter` and `main_thread_wants_to_run` into a data structure that is passed to `thread_fun` rather then have them be globals.

```
condition = threading.Condition()
counter = 0                       # locked by condition
main_thread_wants_to_run = False  # locked by condition

def main_thread(n):
    global counter, main_thread_wants_to_run

    for i in range(n):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_fun, args=(i,))
        thread.start()

    while True:
        with condition:
            main_thread_wants_to_run = True
            condition.wait_for(lambda: counter == 0)
        print("Main thread is running")
        sleep(3) # simulate running taking a few seconds.
        with condition:
            main_thread_wants_to_run = False
            condition.notify_all() # wake up workers
        sleep(60)

def thread_fun(i):
    global main_thread_wants_to_run, counter
    while True:
        with condition:
            condition.wait_for(lambda: not main_thread_wants_to_run)
            counter += 1
        print(i, "child thread")
        with condition:
            counter -= 1
            condition.notify_all()
```